# XSL: Create list items from sentences in running XML text

Tags: xml, list, xslt

I need to tidy up lots of xml texts where lists can be found in running text. The idea is to put the lists in proper list elements instead, so they can be presented in a more consistent way with different stylesheets. Today the numbered lists in running text use 1. 2. 3. or 1) 2) 3), and unnumbered lists use - (hyphen) or *.

My XSL file (which has a structure that fails to collect the list items in a parent list element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"  xmlns:fox="urn:lazy-fox-text" exclude-result-prefixes="fox">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\d\))(\s*(.*))"> 
    <!-- <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\-)(\s*(.*))"> -->
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <item xmlns="urn:lazy-fox-text">
                <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'^[\d]\)\s*','')"/> 
            </item>
        </xsl:matching-substring>

        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A sample input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data xmlns="urn:lazy-fox-text">
  <Text number="1">
    <Title>Lazy dog jumper</Title>
    <Description>It is true, that:  1) The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<p />2) The quick red fox jumps over the lazy dog.<p />3) The old grey fox jumps over the lazy dog. It really does!<p />But I have never seen a cat jumping over that dog.</Description>
  </Text>
  <Text number="2">
    <Title>Lazy foxer</Title>
    <Description>The quick brown fox <arg format="x" /> jumps over the lazy dog owner.<p/>Rules: <p/>-Dogs must be activated.<p/>-Dogs must not sleep all day.</Description>
  </Text>
  <Text number="3">
    <Title>Quickest jumper</Title>
    <Description>The quickest brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<p />The slowest brown fox jumps over the laziest dog.</Description>
<Action>1. Teach the fox not to jump.<p />2. Teach the dog to bark when the fox jumps.</Action>
  </Text>
</Data>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data xmlns="urn:lazy-fox-text">
   <Text number="1">
      <Title>Lazy dog jumper</Title>
      <Description>It is true, that:
        <list type="number">  
          <item>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</item>
          <item>The quick red fox jumps over the lazy dog.</item>
          <item>The old grey fox jumps over the lazy dog. It really does!</item>
       </list>
       <p/>But I have never seen a cat jumping over that dog.
      </Description>
   </Text>
   <Text number="2">
      <Title>Lazy foxer</Title>
      <Description>The quick brown fox <arg format="x"/> jumps over the lazy dog owner.<p/>Rules: <p/>
        <list type="bullet">
            <item>Dogs must be activated.</item>
            <item>Dogs must not sleep all day.<item>
        </list>
      </Description>
   </Text>
   <Text number="3">
      <Title>Quickest jumper</Title>
      <Description>The quickest brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<p/>The slowest brown fox jumps over the laziest dog.</Description>
      <Action>
        <list type="number">  
            <item>Teach the fox not to jump.</item>
            <item>Teach the dog to bark when the fox jumps.</item>
      </Action>
   </Text>
</Data>
```

Comment: So what is the meaning of those `p` elements, they kind of get in the way if you use `analyze-string` as that works on strings. Can the `p` elements be ignored/removed? Can there be other elements inside of text you want to transform into a list item?

Comment: The `p` elements are always "empty". They are used to force a newline. `p` elements will not be needed inside a proper list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to ignore the empty `p` respectively treat them as part of the list if adjacent to text with an item, that way I have a first mode transforming any text starting with number or `-` or `*` into an `item` element, then a second mode that uses `for-each-group group-adjacent` to wrap adjacent `item`s into a `list` and also strips the empty `p`s:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:lazy-fox-text"
    xmlns="urn:lazy-fox-text"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="items" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="lists" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:mode name="strip" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:variable name="items">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="items"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="lists">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$items/node()" mode="lists"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="items">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="([0-9]+[).]|-|\*)(\s*(.*))">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <item numeric="{matches(regex-group(1), '^[0-9]')}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
              </item>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[item]" mode="lists">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::item | self::p[not(node())])">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[self::item]">
                      <list type="{if (current-group()[self::item[@numeric = 'true']]) then 'number' else 'bullet'}">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="strip"/>
                      </list>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="#current"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item/@numeric | p[not(node())]" mode="strip"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$lists"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is not quite as described (`item`s have some preceding white space but I guess you can fix that) and some `p` before lists are swallowed:

```
<Data xmlns="urn:lazy-fox-text">
   <Text number="1">
      <Title>Lazy dog jumper</Title>
      <Description>It is true, that:  <list type="number">
            <item> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</item>
            <item> The quick red fox jumps over the lazy dog.</item>
            <item> The old grey fox jumps over the lazy dog. It really does!</item>
         </list>But I have never seen a cat jumping over that dog.</Description>
   </Text>
   <Text number="2">
      <Title>Lazy foxer</Title>
      <Description>The quick brown fox <arg format="x"/> jumps over the lazy dog owner.<p/>Rules: <list type="bullet">
            <item>Dogs must be activated.</item>
            <item>Dogs must not sleep all day.</item>
         </list>
      </Description>
   </Text>
   <Text number="3">
      <Title>Quickest jumper</Title>
      <Description>The quickest brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<p/>The slowest brown fox jumps over the laziest dog.</Description>
      <Action>
         <list type="number">
            <item> Teach the fox not to jump.</item>
            <item> Teach the dog to bark when the fox jumps.</item>
         </list>
      </Action>
   </Text>
</Data>
```

Code is XSLT 3 so works as posted with Saxon 9.8 all editions or 9.7 PE or EE and with Altova 2017 or 2018, if you need XSLT 2 replace all those `xsl:mode` elements with the identity transformation

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Upgrading to XSLT 3 seems like a really good idea. The solution with modes is working fine. One thing that I found out when testing is that in some languages hyphens are used for forming words, but that will just require some small changes to the regex.